# Метод Безье (сглаживание)

Tags: java, swing, design

Есть ли готовая библиотека для отрисовки линий (на основе произвольного количества точек) используя метод Безье?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562992/java-swing-drawing-curved-lines 
Нашёл аналогичный вопрос, но тут дан ответ только для построения кривой на основе 3 точек